# Rails Browserify React ExecJS error during precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, reactjs, browserify

I've tried out literally all the solutions that are available out there. But I'm stuck with this for the past 24 hours. I am not able to track where the error is.

Here's the error log which I got from `rake assets:precompile --trace`

```
ExecJS::ProgramError: Unexpected token punc «(», expected punc «:» (line: 38085, col: 18, pos: 1133749)

Error
    at new JS_Parse_Error (<eval>:3572:11870)
    at js_error (<eval>:3572:12089)
    at croak (<eval>:3572:20898)
    at token_error (<eval>:3572:21035)
    at expect_token (<eval>:3572:21258)
    at expect (<eval>:3572:21396)
    at <eval>:3572:30647
    at <eval>:3572:21788
    at expr_atom (<eval>:3572:29403)
    at maybe_unary (<eval>:3573:143)
    at expr_ops (<eval>:3573:901)
    at maybe_conditional (<eval>:3573:993)
    at maybe_assign (<eval>:3573:1436)
new JS_Parse_Error ((execjs):3572:11870)
js_error ((execjs):3572:12089)
croak ((execjs):3572:20898)
token_error ((execjs):3572:21035)
expect_token ((execjs):3572:21258)
expect ((execjs):3572:21396)
(execjs):3572:30647
(execjs):3572:21788
expr_atom ((execjs):3572:29403)
maybe_unary ((execjs):3573:143)
expr_ops ((execjs):3573:901)
maybe_conditional ((execjs):3573:993)
maybe_assign ((execjs):3573:1436)
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/execjs-2.6.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:47:in `rescue in block in call'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/execjs-2.6.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:44:in `block in call'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/execjs-2.6.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:75:in `block in lock'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/execjs-2.6.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:73:in `Locker'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/execjs-2.6.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:73:in `lock'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/execjs-2.6.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:43:in `call'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/uglifier-3.0.0/lib/uglifier.rb:176:in `run_uglifyjs'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/uglifier-3.0.0/lib/uglifier.rb:139:in `compile'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/uglifier_compressor.rb:52:in `call'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/uglifier_compressor.rb:28:in `call'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in `load_from_unloaded'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:318:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:66:in `find_asset'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:73:in `find_all_linked_assets'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:142:in `block in find'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:114:in `block (2 levels) in logical_paths'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:225:in `block in stat_tree'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in `block in stat_directory'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:206:in `each'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:206:in `stat_directory'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:224:in `stat_tree'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `each'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `block in logical_paths'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `each'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `logical_paths'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:140:in `find'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:168:in `compile'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.0.4/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:68:in `block (3 levels) in define'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:147:in `with_logger'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.0.4/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:67:in `block (2 levels) in define'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/task.rb:248:in `block in execute'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/task.rb:243:in `each'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/task.rb:243:in `execute'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/task.rb:187:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/task.rb:180:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/task.rb:173:in `invoke'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
V8::Error: Unexpected token punc «(», expected punc «:»
at js_error (<eval>:3572:12089)
at croak (<eval>:3572:20898)
at token_error (<eval>:3572:21035)
at expect_token (<eval>:3572:21258)
at expect (<eval>:3572:21396)
at <eval>:3572:30647
at <eval>:3572:21788
at expr_atom (<eval>:3572:29403)
at maybe_unary (<eval>:3573:143)
at expr_ops (<eval>:3573:901)
at maybe_conditional (<eval>:3573:993)
at maybe_assign (<eval>:3573:1436)
at expression (<eval>:3573:1749)
at expr_list (<eval>:3572:29964)
at subscripts (<eval>:3572:31880)
at subscripts (<eval>:3572:31516)
at expr_atom (<eval>:3572:29621)
at maybe_unary (<eval>:3573:143)
at expr_ops (<eval>:3573:901)
at maybe_conditional (<eval>:3573:993)
at maybe_assign (<eval>:3573:1436)
at expression (<eval>:3573:1749)
at vardefs (<eval>:3572:27739)
at var_ (<eval>:3572:27894)
at <eval>:3572:23683
at <eval>:3572:21788
at block_ (<eval>:3572:26497)
at ctor.body (<eval>:3572:26131)
at function_ (<eval>:3572:26196)
at expr_atom (<eval>:3572:29484)
at maybe_unary (<eval>:3573:143)
at expr_ops (<eval>:3573:901)
at maybe_conditional (<eval>:3573:993)
at maybe_assign (<eval>:3573:1436)
at expression (<eval>:3573:1749)
at expr_list (<eval>:3572:29964)
at <eval>:3572:30078
at <eval>:3572:21788
at expr_atom (<eval>:3572:29355)
at maybe_unary (<eval>:3573:143)
at expr_ops (<eval>:3573:901)
at maybe_conditional (<eval>:3573:993)
at maybe_assign (<eval>:3573:1436)
at expression (<eval>:3573:1749)
at <eval>:3572:30733
at <eval>:3572:21788
at expr_atom (<eval>:3572:29403)
at maybe_unary (<eval>:3573:143)
at expr_ops (<eval>:3573:901)
at maybe_conditional (<eval>:3573:993)
at maybe_assign (<eval>:3573:1436)
at expression (<eval>:3573:1749)
at expr_list (<eval>:3572:29964)
at subscripts (<eval>:3572:31880)
at expr_atom (<eval>:3572:29302)
at maybe_unary (<eval>:3573:143)
at expr_ops (<eval>:3573:901)
at maybe_conditional (<eval>:3573:993)
at maybe_assign (<eval>:3573:1436)
at expression (<eval>:3573:1749)
at simple_statement (<eval>:3572:24461)
at <eval>:3572:22602
at <eval>:3572:21788
at <eval>:3573:2092
at parse (<eval>:3573:2301)
at parse (<eval>:3903:22)
at uglifier (<eval>:3946:13)
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/execjs-2.6.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:45:in `block in call'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/execjs-2.6.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:75:in `block in lock'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/execjs-2.6.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:73:in `Locker'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/execjs-2.6.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:73:in `lock'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/execjs-2.6.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:43:in `call'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/uglifier-3.0.0/lib/uglifier.rb:176:in `run_uglifyjs'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/uglifier-3.0.0/lib/uglifier.rb:139:in `compile'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/uglifier_compressor.rb:52:in `call'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/uglifier_compressor.rb:28:in `call'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in `load_from_unloaded'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:318:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:66:in `find_asset'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:73:in `find_all_linked_assets'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:142:in `block in find'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:114:in `block (2 levels) in logical_paths'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:225:in `block in stat_tree'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in `block in stat_directory'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:206:in `each'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:206:in `stat_directory'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:224:in `stat_tree'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `each'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `block in logical_paths'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `each'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `logical_paths'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:140:in `find'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:168:in `compile'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.0.4/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:68:in `block (3 levels) in define'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:147:in `with_logger'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.0.4/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:67:in `block (2 levels) in define'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/task.rb:248:in `block in execute'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/task.rb:243:in `each'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/task.rb:243:in `execute'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/task.rb:187:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/task.rb:180:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/task.rb:173:in `invoke'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/karthik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
```

Here's the stack that I use:

1. Rails
2. ReactJS
3. NPM
4. Bower
5. Browserify
6. Reactify

Please help me out on this! Thanks in advance. Is there any way I can track in which file the error is?

Comment: Maybe try getting out of the Rails asset pipeline altogether by doing something like http://developers.mobilesystem7.com/blog/post/replacing-rails-asset-pipeline-with-grunt-bower-browserify/ ?

Comment: @SteveJorgensen Thanks for the suggestion Steve. Will give it a shot now. 